# How do I make a square and label each corner with a number?

Tags: labels, tikz-shape

I am trying to make a square to demonstrate how reflections and rotations work, so I would like a square with each interior vertex labeled with a number.

Comment: I love the massive variety of answers!

Comment: ow, I returned here and found 7 answers! Nice!

Comment: By now it seems that only PStricks and Asymptote are missing! Only a matter of time, I hope, before they come ;-)

Comment: @fpast Those aren't the *only* possibilities left... ;-)

Comment: @fpast I was also going to point out that it can be done using hyphens inside \resizeboxes, but I think I've done enough damage to this thread already.

Comment: @Ryan What damage? To the contrary, your answers are quite instructive.

Comment: After seeing all those 11 answers I remembered a possible answer to that so popular question on TeX.SE: "why LaTeX is better than MS Word?" I would say: "try to do this using it".

Answer (score 9):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (2,2) -- (2,0) -- (0,0);
\node[above right] at (0,0) {1};
\node[below right] at (0,2) {2};
\node[below left] at (2,2) {3};
\node[above left] at (2,0) {4};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

An automatic and easy way to adapt (following idea of @Benjamin McKay)

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[blue,draw=red,thick,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=2cm] (rect) at (0,0) {$\times$};
\foreach \anc/\n in {south west/1,north west/2,north east/3,south east/4}{
\node[anchor=\anc] at (rect.\anc) {\n};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Quite an easy game for every TeXian drawing solution. By the way, did you try one of them?

Here with MetaPost via LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\mplibsetformat{metafun}
    \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    u = 4cm; draw unitsquare scaled u;
    label.urt("1", origin); label.ulft("2", (u, 0));
    label.llft("3", (u, u)); label.lrt("4", (0, u));
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit** And now a `mfpic` solution. I've chosen to place it here and not as a separate answer because `mfpic` acts as an interface to MetaPost (it could have been to METAFONT by the way). It gives exactly the same result as above, is written only  with `(La)TeX` macros but needs three compilations (by LaTeX, then by MetaPost, then by LaTeX again).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[metapost]{mfpic}
\setlength{\mfpicunit}{4cm}
\opengraphsfile{\jobname}
\begin{document}
\begin{mfpic}{0}{1}{0}{1}
    \rect{(0,0), (1, 1)}
    \tlpointsep{3bp}
    \tlabels{[bl](0,0){1} [br](1,0){2} [tr](1,1){3} [tl](0,1){4}}
\end{mfpic}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The most standard LaTeX (not TeX ;-)) graphic solution: the `picture` environment. No packages loaded thus.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{4cm}
\begin{picture}(1,1)
    \put(0,0){\framebox(1,1)[t]{}}
    \put(0.01,0.01){1}
    \put(0.99,0.01){\makebox(0,0)[br]{2}}
    \put(0.99,0.99){\makebox(0,0)[tr]{3}}
    \put(0.01,0.99){\makebox(0,0)[tl]{4}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May be a `tabular` :P

Answer (score 3):

The solution based only on TeX primitives (without TikZ, Metapost, Lua etc.):

```
\def\hboxlab#1#2{\hbox to2cm{\vrule height4mm depth1mm \kern1mm #1\hfil #2\kern1mm\vrule}}
\vbox{\offinterlineskip\hrule
      \hboxlab 43
      \hbox to2cm{\vrule height1cm \hfil\vrule}
      \hboxlab 12
      \hrule
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's quite possibly the strangest approach, using `XeLaTeX` and `fontspec` to type the unicode ballot box symbol, resizing it using a `\resizebox`, and then putting the numbers inside that by manipulating the kerning and alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\arial}{Arial Unicode MS}

\begin{document}
    \resizebox{2in}{!}{\arial ☐}\textbf{
    \kern-1.68in\raisebox{1.35in}{1}
    \kern-1.8ex\raisebox{.22in}{3}
    \kern1in\raisebox{1.35in}{2}
    \kern-2ex\raisebox{.22in}{4}}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

*This is questionably functional and slightly ugly, and not actually intended as a serious answer.*

Answer (score 3):

Just to flood this post ;-)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\fboxsep2pt
\fboxrule1pt
\fbox{%
\parbox[t][4cm]{4cm}{%
4 \hfill 3
\par\vfill
1 \hfill 2
}%
}

\begin{tabular*}{4cm}{|@{\,\extracolsep\fill}lr@{\,}|}
\hline
4 & 3\\[3cm]
1 & 2\\\hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Those are both really elegant solutions, especially the table!

Answer (score 3):

This is addicting.

Here's a *one line* answer, using the boxed equation command in the `amsmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[\boxed{1 \kern6ex 2\raisebox{-6.75ex}{\kern-8.25ex 3 \kern5ex 4}}\]

\end{document}
```

> [image]

*This is fully functional and technically correct, but not actually intended as a serious answer.*

Answer (score 2):

Here, I stack inside a simple `\framebox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\stackinset{l}{2pt}{t}{2pt}{4}{%
\stackinset{r}{2pt}{t}{2pt}{3}{%
\stackinset{r}{2pt}{b}{2pt}{2}{%
\stackinset{l}{2pt}{b}{2pt}{1}{%
  \framebox(50,50){}%
}}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If coloring and centermark are useful,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\stackinset{l}{2pt}{t}{2pt}{4}{%
\stackinset{r}{2pt}{t}{2pt}{3}{%
\stackinset{r}{2pt}{b}{2pt}{2}{%
\stackinset{l}{2pt}{b}{2pt}{1}{%
  \textcolor{red}{\framebox(50,50){\textcolor{blue}{$\times$}}}%
}}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just because nobody has done it yet, here's a solution* using nothing but `\vspace`, `\hspace`, and `\rule`:

No packages loaded, and not too many lines of code!

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \noindent\rule{25ex}{.4pt}\\
    \hspace*{.25ex} 1 \hspace{19ex} 2 \vspace*{-1.1\baselineskip}\\
    \rule{.4pt}{25ex} \hspace{23.265ex} \rule{.4pt}{25ex}\vspace*{-1.5\baselineskip}\\
    \hspace*{.25ex} 3 \hspace{19ex} 4 \vspace*{-.5\baselineskip}\\
    \rule{25ex}{.4pt}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

*This is fully functional and technically correct, but not actually intended as a serious answer.*

Answer (score 2):

Since nobody has volunteered for it yet, here is a solution with [Asymptote,](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net) using the aptly named `asymptote` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
    unitsize(4cm);
    draw(unitsquare);
    label("1", (0, 0), NE); label("2", (1, 0), NW);
    label("3", (1, 1), SW); label("4", (0, 1), SE);
\end{asy}     
\end{document}
```

To be compiled thrice, too: once with LaTeX, then once with Asymptote (`asy myfile.asy` in an Unix command line interface, for example) and then once again with LaTeX.

[image]